# how to add library to vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a vue-cli project and i want to add my library to it and want it to run globally in all components i tried to write it as a script tags in **index.html** but it doesn't work...

```
<script src="src/services/rusha.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/services/eev.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var BUS = new Eev()
  var STATE = {}
</script>
<script src="src/services/subscriptions.gui.js" data-service="segell" data-enabledroles="principal,employee"></script>
```

i tried also to make script tag from **main.js** in created(){}  function and also not worked

```
let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'src/services/eev.min.js')
document.body.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
```

the purpose of code is that should to make emit event to backend with the credentials and then i can make http req to it

```
BUS.emit('interaction', {
  screen: 'loginasprincipal',
  customerid: '10386',
  password: '100101995610053'
})
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a plugin for it. You can globally register it with `Vue.use`. Here is the documentation for it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin

Comment: Also why do you need a third party event dispatcher? Here is how you can use event bus globally (a regular new Vue instance): https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: i don't need to emit event between components i want to emit it to the backend server

Comment: That last comment confuses me. The event bus does not talk to your backend server, it's only for communication inside the browser (which vue h as built in). You might be looking for a websocket or ajax library?

Comment: in the last comment BUS is not the event bus in the vue but it in my library that i want to import in vue